# how to pass variable from one test to another in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I use pytest and to perform next tests I have to pass a variable to them (product_id), e.g:

```
def test_1():
    product = Product()
    product.enter_name('product1')
    product.add_price(2)
    product.add()
    product_id = driver.find_element_by_name('id')

def test_2():
    driver.get('http://example.com/{}'.format(product_id)
    ...
```

how can i do this?

Comment: I know unit test better than pytest, but I would hazard a guess that you need to make a test class and then have an object variable that you can reference.

Comment: Found some [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/getting-started.html#group-multiple-tests-in-a-class) that might help you.

Comment: Thank you bro, I'll check it in the morning.

Comment: In many cases the answer is "you don't", because you want to be able to run tests individually. It's also possible that tests will not run in the order you expect. Better to fact out the common code into a setup function/class method, and have it called by each test.

Comment: I realize that this is not a perfect solution, but at present it is the easiest way to solve my problem this way. I am still looking  a way to pass variables.

Comment: I know there was such a thing as Namespace before, but it was removed from Pytest 4.0.